# how to send a mail by telnetting through some SMTP server?

Tags: cisco, smtp

I wanted to send a mail by telnetting through smtp server "telnet smtp_Server 25" and want to send mail. How is it possible..

Also, please share something about CISCO products and what kind of software they use in their products. If i wanted to gain some insight knowledge, where should go to..

Thanks..

Comment: Do not put two questions into one. Post two separate questions please. Also, it helps to be specific. "share something about CISCO" is unlikely to get meaningful responses.

Comment: This is an awful idea for a couple of reasons. One: most public servers (not owned by you) are now locked down to prevent spam relaying. Two: this is probably illegal (due to CAN-SPAM act); I could be wrong, but I wouldn't discount the possibility.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like two distinct questions...

[SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is a fairly simple protocol (at least for just sending an email)... once you open a telnet connection on the right port you just need to issue the commands:

From Wikipedia: (commands you issue are prefixed with "C:" the servers responses with "S:")

```
S: 220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix
C: HELO relay.example.org
S: 250 Hello relay.example.org, I am glad to meet you
C: MAIL FROM:<bob@example.org>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<alice@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<theboss@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: DATA
S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
C: From: "Bob Example" <bob@example.org>
C: To: Alice Example <alice@example.com>
C: Cc: theboss@example.com
C: Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2008 16:02:43 -0500
C: Subject: Test message
C:
C: Hello Alice.
C: This is a test message with 5 header fields and 4 lines in the message body.
C: Your friend,
C: Bob
C: .
S: 250 Ok: queued as 12345
C: QUIT
S: 221 Bye
```

Good luck with Cisco... you should ask it a as a separate questions or explain how it's related.

Comment: The steps i know, but i dont know the name of smtp server, which i can use for sending email.. Any free smtp server name for testing this protocol..

Comment: smtp.gmail.com PORT 25

Why do you need to "test" SMTP?  It works.

Comment: because I have tried smtp.gmail.com.. But it doesn't works..
must issue a starttls command first,, and when i use,, the connection is automatically closed.. what is this,, and how to resolve this..

Comment: You can't use gmail as it forces encryption.  Why do you even need this?

Comment: sIR, i wANTED TO DO IT THRU TELNET.. FOR THAT I NEED TO HAVE FREE SMTP SERVER.. iS THERE ANY??

Comment: What you're looking for is called an open relay.  Why do you need to send via telnet?  I would recommend sending through the SMTP relay provided by your ISP for outgoing mail, or at worst do a DNS lookup and connect to the SMTP server published in the recipient's MX record as it should accept mail for the receipient's address.

Answer (score 1):

You're not likely to find an SMTP server that will let you telnet in since that would provide a potential wide-open door for spammers.

Comment: Unless of course that server is provided by your ISP

Answer (score 1):

you can easily make you own SMTP server on almost any nix system, and it should work provided you don't have any firewall rules in the way

Comment: How can i make my own SMTP Server,, Any website link??

Comment: ask on ubuntu forums, they have alot of good tutorials for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP usually provides you with one you can access, if not - at least they'll have a relay you can authenticate and send e-mail through from an smtp server you set up yourself.